# Fast image change detection algorithm

Tags: performance, image, comparison, vnc

I am looking for an algorithm to calculate areas that have changed between two images. I need it for a RFB (VNC) implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting one Image from another would be a good start.

Comment: Subtracting the images is not my problem. I already have a list of points which are different, but now I need an algorithm to calculate rectangles with points that lay near together.